# musixtex bars not visible

Tags: musixtex

So, I am trying to typeset an article using `\LaTeX` that needs to have `musixtex`. To make things easier I made a few macros. Things are working OK, except I can't seem to get any (musical) vertical bar lines (other than microscopic dots). Accomplishing nothing, I rewrote my macros in vanilla `\TeX`, which... accomplished nothing. My document is *sorta* like:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% Emits a pitchless duration (stems up). Hides the ugliness of musixtex.
% Usage: \beat{duration}
% Where: duration in [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64].
\def\beat#1{
\ifnum#1=1
{\wh{i}} % whole
\else{
    \ifnum#1=2
    {\hu{i}} % half
    \else{
        \ifnum#1=4
        {\qu{i}} % quarter
        \else{
            \ifnum#1=8
            {\cu{i}} % eighth
            \else{
                \ifnum#1=16 
                {\ccu{i}} % sixteenth
                \else{
                    \ifnum#1=32 
                    {\cccu{i}} % thirty-second 
                    \else{{\ccccu{i}}}\fi % sixty-fourth
                }\fi
            }\fi
        }\fi
    }\fi
}\fi
}

% Emits a single measure.
% Usage: \measure{notes}
% Where: notes is a sequence of \beat{?} or \rest{?}
\def\measure#1{\Notes #1\en\bar}

% Null clef.
\def\nullclef{\raise2\internote\hbox{\keychar77}}

% Emits a single-line staff rhythmic example with one or 
% more measures.
% Usage: \rhythm{num}{den}{measures}
% Where: num, den are the meter.
%        measures is one or more \measure{notes}
\def\rhythm#1#2#3{\begin{music}
    \nobarnumbers
    \instrumentnumber{1}
    \generalmeter{\meterfrac{#1}{#2}}
    \setstaffs1{1}
    \setclefsymbol1{\nullclef}
    \setlines1{1}
    \sepbarrules
    \startextract
    #3
    \endextract
\end{music}}

\begin{document}

\title{Rhythmic Whatnot}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Stuff about rhythmic structure with machine learning.
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}

Waffle on forever. For example, with $n = 4$ and $\left\{2, 1, 1\right\}$, then:

\rhythm{2}{4}{
    \measure{\beat{4}\beat{8}\beat{8}}
    \measure{\beat{8}\beat{4}\beat{8}}
    \measure{\beat{8}\beat{8}\beat{4}}
    }

Therefore, it is obvious.

\end{document}
```

I imagine that there is just one simple thing that I am doing wrong, but I can't see it, even after days of fooling with it.

Comment: Welcome to very beautiful word of TEX.SE. The microscopic dots are similar to the eye? Please, could you also add a confirmation image?

Comment: For whatever reason, `\bar` which I presume was redefined by `musictex` is not working as you are expecting it to.

Comment: I get [this output (click here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3eiz.png), which seems quite fine.

Comment: @egreg I do not get that output.  and my LaTeX installation (MikTeX) occurred earlier today, so I am fresh out of the box.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes There may be conflicts (for `\breve`, perhaps), but certainly not with `\bar` which is redefined in a `music` environment. I'm using `MusiXTeX(c) 1.28 <2018-05-07>`. On the other hand, the problem is reproducible with `MusiXTeX(c) 1.27 <2017-12-26>`

Comment: @egreg The file introducing the difference in those two versions is `generic/musixtex.tex`. With a quick look at the diff, I sadly cannot see the reason what is causing the different `\bar` behavior.

Comment: Can you please look in the log file for the version of MusiXTeX you're using?

Comment: @egreg see my updated answer, found it.

Comment: Anyway, this has nothing to do with `amsmath`.

Answer (score 4):

## Update

This is a bug related to `MusiXTeX(c) 1.27 <2017-12-26>`, fixed in `MusiXTeX(c) 1.28 <2018-05-07>`. You should update that package.

In case you can't update, you can fix this bug manually in your document. Add the following to your preamble and ignore my original answer:

```
\usepackage{regexpatch}

\makeatletter
\regexpatchcmd{\C@Inter}{=}{<}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\C@Inter}{\thr@@}{\f@ur}{}{}
\makeatother
```

Full MWE (version 1.27):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% to fix a bug in musixtex version <1.28
\usepackage{regexpatch}

\makeatletter
\regexpatchcmd{\C@Inter}{=}{<}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\C@Inter}{\thr@@}{\f@ur}{}{}
\makeatother
% end fix

% Emits a pitchless duration (stems up). Hides the ugliness of musixtex.
% Usage: \beat{duration}
% Where: duration in [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64].
\def\beat#1{
  \ifnum#1=1
  {\wh{i}} % whole
  \else{
    \ifnum#1=2
    {\hu{i}} % half
    \else{
      \ifnum#1=4
      {\qu{i}} % quarter
      \else{
        \ifnum#1=8
        {\cu{i}} % eighth
        \else{
          \ifnum#1=16 
          {\ccu{i}} % sixteenth
          \else{
            \ifnum#1=32 
            {\cccu{i}} % thirty-second 
            \else{{\ccccu{i}}}\fi % sixty-fourth
          }\fi
        }\fi
      }\fi
    }\fi
  }\fi
}

% Emits a single measure.
% Usage: \measure{notes}
% Where: notes is a sequence of \beat{?} or \rest{?}
\def\measure#1{\Notes #1\en\bar}
\def\measuree#1{\Notes #1\en}

% Null clef.
\def\nullclef{\raise2\internote\hbox{\keychar77}}

% Emits a single-line staff rhythmic example with one or 
% more measures.
% Usage: \rhythm{num}{den}{measures}
% Where: num, den are the meter.
%        measures is one or more \measure{notes}
\def\rhythm#1#2#3{\begin{music}
  \nobarnumbers
  \instrumentnumber{1}
  \generalmeter{\meterfrac{#1}{#2}}
  \setstaffs1{1}
  \setclefsymbol1{\nullclef}
  \setlines1{1}
  \sepbarrules
  \startextract
  #3%
  \endextract
\end{music}}

\begin{document}

  \title{Rhythmic Whatnot}
  \maketitle

  \begin{abstract}
    Stuff about rhythmic structure with machine learning.
  \end{abstract}

  \section{Introduction}

  Waffle on forever. For example, with $n = 4$ and $\left\{2, 1, 1\right\}$, then:

  \rhythm{2}{4}{%
    \measure{\beat{4}\beat{8}\beat{8}}
    \measure{\beat{8}\beat{4}\beat{8}}
    \measuree{\beat{8}\beat{8}\beat{4}}%
  }

  Therefore, it is obvious.

\end{document}
```

[image: result]

**The technical details:** Reading helps, as in the `1.28` changelog is written

> ```
> % version 1.28
>
> % defined 
> %  \z[left|right|leftright]repeat, for use *within* a bar
> %  \zz...repeat, to force to the end of a system
> % corrected definition of \C@Inter for \nblines < 4
> ```

If one looks up the definition

```
\def\C@Inter{%  RDT: corrected to work if \nblines > 6   (version 1.23)
```

in line 1831 (v1.27) or in line 1838 (v1.28), one finds the following `diff`

```
<   \ifnum\nblines=\thr@@
---
>   \ifnum\nblines<\f@ur
```

Hence I consider this a bug and one should update, but as a workaround, my presented solution seems to work.

---

## Original answer

Not sure why @egreg seems to get the desired (?) result already, but I found a fix for `MusiXTeX(c) 1.27 <2017-12-26>`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% Emits a pitchless duration (stems up). Hides the ugliness of musixtex.
% Usage: \beat{duration}
% Where: duration in [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64].
\def\beat#1{
  \ifnum#1=1
  {\wh{i}} % whole
  \else{
    \ifnum#1=2
    {\hu{i}} % half
    \else{
      \ifnum#1=4
      {\qu{i}} % quarter
      \else{
        \ifnum#1=8
        {\cu{i}} % eighth
        \else{
          \ifnum#1=16 
          {\ccu{i}} % sixteenth
          \else{
            \ifnum#1=32 
            {\cccu{i}} % thirty-second 
            \else{{\ccccu{i}}}\fi % sixty-fourth
          }\fi
        }\fi
      }\fi
    }\fi
  }\fi
}

% Emits a single measure.
% Usage: \measure{notes}
% Where: notes is a sequence of \beat{?} or \rest{?}
\def\measure#1{\Notes #1\en\bar}
\def\measuree#1{\Notes #1\en} % <-- added

% Null clef.
\def\nullclef{\raise2\internote\hbox{\keychar77}}

% Emits a single-line staff rhythmic example with one or 
% more measures.
% Usage: \rhythm{num}{den}{measures}
% Where: num, den are the meter.
%        measures is one or more \measure{notes}
\def\rhythm#1#2#3{\begin{music}
  \nobarnumbers
  \instrumentnumber{1}
  \generalmeter{\meterfrac{#1}{#2}}
  \setstaffs1{1}
  \setclefsymbol1{\nullclef}
  \setlines1{1}
  \sepbarrules
  \startextract\setlines1{5}% <-- added
  #3%
  \endextract
\end{music}}

\begin{document}

  \title{Rhythmic Whatnot}
  \maketitle

  \begin{abstract}
    Stuff about rhythmic structure with machine learning.
  \end{abstract}

  \section{Introduction}

  Waffle on forever. For example, with $n = 4$ and $\left\{2, 1, 1\right\}$, then:

  \rhythm{2}{4}{%
    \measure{\beat{4}\beat{8}\beat{8}}
    \measure{\beat{8}\beat{4}\beat{8}}
    \measuree{\beat{8}\beat{8}\beat{4}}% <-- changed
  }

  Therefore, it is obvious.

\end{document}
```

[image: image result]

It seems that `\bar` creates the bar depending on the height of the lines. If you change that after `\startextract`, you're able to modify the bars without affecting the printed lines. Not sure if this is a feature though.

I also created a new macro `\measuree` for "measure end" without a bar to remove the double bar at the end.

Comment: SpexTeXular @nox! Yes, I was using the v1.27 MusiXTex, and although I did examine the log file, sometimes it takes a TeXnician, and I am no way there yet.